# "IntentReceiver components are not allowed to register to receive intents" when trying to determine Battery level

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I am trying to get Battery info from my Application following the guidelines at http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html

This is the method is came up with to check the battery level:

```
public void sendBatteryInfoMessage(){

    IntentFilter iFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
    Intent batteryStatus = c.registerReceiver(null, iFilter);

    int status = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
    boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING || status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;

    int chargePlug = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
    boolean isUsbCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
    boolean isAcCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC;

    int batteryLevel = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
    int scale = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);

    float batteryPct = batteryLevel / (float) scale;

}
```

`c` is initialized as `Context` object earlier in the class.

This is the error message I am getting

```
    07-24 18:11:23.445      634-634/wifi.myapp.sudara.lk.sudara_app W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40028890)
07-24 18:11:23.485      634-634/wifi.myapp.sudara.lk.sudara_app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver wifi.myapp.sudara.lk.sudara_app.SmsActivity: android.content.ReceiverCallNotAllowedException: IntentReceiver components are not allowed to register to receive intents
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2821)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3200(ActivityThread.java:125)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2083)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.content.ReceiverCallNotAllowedException: IntentReceiver components are not allowed to register to receive intents
            at android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:138)
            at android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:132)
            at wifi.myapp.sudara.lk.sudara_app.BatteryInfo.sendBatteryInfoMessage(BatteryInfo.java:25)
            at wifi.myapp.sudara.lk.sudara_app.SmsActivity.onReceive(SmsActivity.java:53)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2810)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3200(ActivityThread.java:125)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2083)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What I need to know is the meaning of `IntentReceiver components are not allowed to register to receive intents` and how to over come it.

Thank you

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Instead of:

```
c.registerReceiver(null, iFilter)
```

use:

```
c.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(null, iFilter)
```

The `Context` that is passed to `onReceive()` is blocked from calling `registerReceiver()`, even with a `null` `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: What if my receivers are registered in the AndroidManifest instead?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky: I am not aware that you can get that error for receivers registered in the manifest.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am seeing this same error on android versions 4.1.2 and less even when I employ this solution. Any ideas of how this can be happening even if I am converting the context to the application context before registering the receiver?

Comment: @neonDion: off the cuff, I don't know why you would get that, outside of OS or OEM bugs. You might want to post a separate question.